# How to bind to an ASP.NET UpdatePanel event using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, updatepanel

Nutshell version: I need to know how to bind a JavaScript function to be called whenever any UpdatePanel on the website updates.

Detailed version: I have a survey website that we are building for a client. The website utilizes jQuery Mobile, so that all the controls are rendered for mobile devices as well as the web. This works great overall.

The problem is that anything that is in an ASP.NET UpdatePanel, when the panel refreshes with new info, the controls do not get re-rendered by jQuery mobile. In other words, when the page first loads, all the controls are stylized, but if an UpdatePanel updates, all the controls in the panel lose their styling and go back to their default look.

The fix for this is easy enough, I just need to call 'create' on the div(s) that were updated, for example:

```
$('div').trigger('create');
```

And the 'create' will re-parse the controls in the given DIV and stylize them. And when it is MY UpdatePanel and MY controls, I can "hardwire" that call in there.

On one page however, we are using a ReportViewer control. The problem here is that the ReportViewer renders it's own output including wrapping everything in an UpdatePanel, the minute you select an option from the Dropdown, all the styling is lost.

I need a way (jQuery .bind() comes to mind) to bind to any UpdatePanel(s) on the page, and if they refresh, call the 'create' function.

I do have a master page on the site, which would be perfect (I think) for putting this code into. I just don't know what to key in on, or what the syntax would be.

Any ideas/thoughts/suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You can bind to the load event, it fires when an element has finished loading new content.

```
$('div').load(function () {
  $(this).trigger('create');
});
```

Comment: I can call the trigger create from the console and it redraws the object, however, if I bind it to load it doesn't redraw. Any ideas?

Comment: It just looks like this:`$('#updateTable').load(function () {
        $(this).trigger('create');
    })` if I simply call `$('#updateTable').trigger('create');` from the console, the styling appears again, I just haven't been able to bind it to load

Comment: @avivas Recreate the problem in jsFiddle and I might be able to help you. Anyway, you should probably ask a new question. Discussing this via comments is pointless.